# How to create a dictionary that contains key value pairs from a text file

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

```
('fpcs', (2964, 29))
('fpf1', (32, 8))
('fnf2', (295, 29))
('fnf3', (4850, 89))
('fnf4', (567, 11))
('fpf3', (5660, 76))
('fpf2', (359, 21))


{'fpcs' : 29 , 'fpf1' : 8 , 'fnf2' : 29 , 'fnf3' : 89 , 'fnf4' : 11 , 'fpf3' 
: 76 , 'fpf2' : 21}
```

1st part are my text file text file contents (I dont want the first value in the 
    inner bracket):
and
2nd part is the ouput 
can anyone help me plz
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rough Steps:

- read file
- check input lines
- create dictionary

Example code

```
import re

def dict_from_file(file_path):
    my_dictionary = {}
    with open(file_path) as fh:  # get a file handler for the file
        for line in fh.readlines()  # get each line
            m = re.match("expression", line)  # is your line in an expected form?
            if m:  # consider checking for duplicates too
                 my_dictionary[m.group(1)] = int(m.group(2))
            else:
                 print "could not parse line: {}".format(line)
    return my_dictionary
```

In the current form, you could use the following as your regular expression
`\(\'(\w+)\', \(\d+, (\d+)\)\)`

```
m = re.match("\(\'(\w+)\', \(\d+, (\d+)\)\)", line)
```

Here's an example of it in action: https://regex101.com/r/nPeegL/2